# Austrian-hungarian map: Franzisco-Josephinische (3) Landesaufnahme - Legend

Tags: cartography, legend, maps, history

Currently I work with the Franzisco-Josephinische (3) Landesaufnahme (Austria-Hungary) map in area around Lake Neusiedel. There are some map sheets around Vienna with the scale of 1:12.500 
In the legend there are different fonts for different objects (e.g. mountains, villages, cultures): [https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Abkürzungsverzeichnis,_Zeichenschlüssel_der_GKM.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Abk%C3%BCrzungsverzeichnis,_Zeichenschl%C3%BCssel_der_GKM.jpg)

Within the map there are small area which are labeled with "H" and "W": 
[image: area around Jois/Goysz, 1:12.500 withe "H" and "W"]

I exclude woods/Wälder for "W" because some area have never been woods.
I assume H: heather, commen grazing ground/Hutweide 
and W: meadow/Wiese or grazing ground with one particualr owner.

Does anybody know the the meaning of H/W or know a reference?
(Sorry if wrong exchange, but most people working with maps are here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legend you have linked is from a different mapset with larger scale: [Generalkarte 1:200000](http://lazarus.elte.hu/hun/digkonyv/topo/200e/34-48.jpg).

For the Spezialkarte 1:75000, the legend is at [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Abk%C3%BCrzungsverzeichnis,_Zeichenschl%C3%BCssel_der_Spezialkarte.jpg)

Your image is from the Aufnahmeblatt 1:12500, but no legend is available for that.

You can compare the same place on the Spezalkarte 1:75000 at [mapire](http://mapire.eu/de/map/hkf_75e/?bbox=1854432.4167490776%2C6093394.659036353%2C1883784.2356105854%2C6105471.709505411). There, the Goyszer Haide is rendered as meadow, so Heide and Wiese shoud be the right explanation.

Comment: I ask at the sccessor organisation of the military geography insititute (the BEV) and they answered also tha H stands for Haide/heather and W for Wiese/meadow.